# Can I block connection between a pod and ElastiCache in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, calico

I have my K8s setup(Pods A,B and C) and Elastic cache ("xxx.xxxx.xx.cache.amazonaws.com")in AWS. Right now all my pods have access to elastic cache.

I am looking for a solution by which I can restrict the communication. I read about calico but I understand I can block communication between two pods. Is there any way I can allow A to communicate with xxx.xxxx.xx.cache.amazonaws.com but block Pods B and C.

PS: Elastice cache is not something reside inside the k8s cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kubernetes [network policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) where you can define egress policy to allow/deny outgoing traffic to CIDR blocks or IPs from pods selected by a label.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
        except: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

Above example blocks traffic to 10.0.0.0/24 on port 5978 from pods with label `role: db`

A network plugin such as calico is needed for it work. Follow [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html) to install calico in EKS cluster.

Comment: I should have calio to use networkpolicy in AWS EKS.?

Comment: What is the CNI implementation you already have? Calico or something else?

Comment: amazon-k8s-cni:v1.5.3

Comment: I don't have anything extra. I just created my eks cluster. So do have to add calico or I can directly use network policy?

Comment: Yes you need to install calico https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html

Comment: I am stuck at the option I need to select for "xxx.xxxx.xx.cache.amazonaws.com". I guess there in no option dns name in calico network policy

Comment: there is something called global network policy and also check Tigera enterprise may support  dns